# How to send a mail using gmail smtp in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, email, smtp

I want to send an email from my Gmail account through the website. how do I do that? I've tried every possible way but couldn't get the desired output.

```
public  function mailuser(){
    $config = Array(protocol' => 'ssmtp','smtp_host' => 'ssl://ssmtp.gmail.com','smtp_port' => 465,'smtp_user' => 'xxxx@gmail.com','smtp_pass' => 'xxxx','mailtype'  => 'html');
    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from('xxxx@gmail.com', 'Manoj');
    $this->email->to('xxxxx@gmail.com'); 
    $this->email->subject('Email Subject');
    $this->email->message('Email Message');

    if($this->email->send()){
        echo 'Success email Sent';
        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
    }
    else{
        echo 'Email Failed To Send';
        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you enabled the third party app access on your Google account? Moreover check if you have an email.php file in the config folder, if I'm right codeigniter use the email.php configuration as default if available.

Comment: yes ive enabled third-party access. I wasnt aware about email.php config. let me check it one more time. And thanks btw

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using wrong parameters in config like `ssmtp`

`protocol' => 'ssmtp','smtp_host' => 'ssl://ssmtp.gmail.com'`

Your config array should look like :

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'xxxx@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => 'xxx',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
);

$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

// Set to, from, message, etc.
$this->email->from('xxxx@gmail.com', 'Manoj');
$this->email->to('xxxxx@gmail.com'); 
$this->email->subject('Email Subject');
$this->email->message('Email Message');

$result = $this->email->send();
```

> Also verify to enable extension `extension=php_openssl.dll` in `php.ini`.
>   if not please remove `;`

Comment: @ManoharShinde Is your extension `extension=php_openssl.dll` is enabled in php.ini ? if not please remove `;` and check back again.